# How do I pass in dictionary to function?

Tags: swift2

I'm trying to use functional programming concepts with Swift2 (so please don't recommend using classes).  I'm a beginner in Swift and static typing.

So without using classes how do I pass in a Dictionary Value that is a Dictionary itself to a function.  For example:

```
func recordStrokes(strokes: Int, forHole:Int, var scoreCard: Dictionary<Int, Int>) -> [Int:Int]{
    scoreCard[forHole] = strokes
    return scoreCard
}


var player1 = [ "name": "Lionel","score": [:]]

player1["score"] = recordStrokes(3, forHole: 1, scoreCard: player1["score"])
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to keep a running total of a golf round.  When I use the code above I get the errror:

> error: cannot subscript a value of type '[String : NSObject]' with an index of type 'String'

and

> note: overloads for 'subscript' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (DictionaryIndex), (Key), (Range), (Self.Index)
>   recordStrokes(3, forHole: 1, scoreCard: player1["score"])

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Functional programming doesn't mean that you can't use classes. You can't really use pure functional programming in Swift anyway, you can only use functional patterns in some specific cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

type of scoreCard passed to your function is not correct ...

```
func recordStrokes(strokes: Int, forHole:Int, var scoreCard: Dictionary<Int, Int>) -> [Int:Int]{
    scoreCard[forHole] = strokes
    return scoreCard
}


var player1:[String:Any] = [ "name": "Lionel","score": [Int:Int]()]

let ps = player1["score"] as! [Int:Int]
player1["score"] = recordStrokes(3, forHole: 1, scoreCard: ps)

print(player1) // ["score": [1: 3], "name": "Lionel"]
```

by the way, it has nothing related to functional style paradigm if you use classes or structures in your code. your code (as this snippet) is not written in functional style ...

Comment: What does the `as!` do?  Why do you need to execute [Int:Int] in the player1 Dictionary?  Also my understanding of functional programming is avoiding state and mutable data.  What am I missing?  Is it that I'm changing the data in the dictionary when I pass it through the function?  I thought that as long as state and behavior are not being kept in the function then the function is not managing state, but perhaps that's a misconception.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: as! cast Any to [Int:Int], what is our type of value in dictionary player1 where key is "score". in your snippet the value is [:]. your snippet doesn't compile (because [:] is unknown type of dictionary, except you import Foundation. in case you import Foundation, the compiler try to solve which type is your dictionary with help of 'free bridging'.

Comment: in that case you player1 will be type [String:NSObject] and so value of player1["score"] / [:] / is NSObject. but you declare the function recordStrokes so, that it accepts [Int:Int]. this is source of your error messages, because the type of [:] is unknown, the compiler is not able to recognised its type.

Comment: your player1 is var and you change its state with function recordStrokes. easy solution is to define let player1 and assign the result of recordScore to other let (constant). so no one change it state ...